# Getting error while generating heatmap in python:ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=()

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, grid, heatmap

I am getting errors while generating maps of h3 moments in python for an image file called "image_test". The error apparently is for the shape of the values that I am getting for h3. My goal is to just take the h3 values that I get from h3[ycell][xcell] in my code and then use the values to create a red-blue heatmap in the x-y grid. The link to my code (image_stats.ipynb) in my drive is below. The code uses a file "image_test" which needs to be downloaded for code to run.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gXWSuxsOHHaNV5Qv-C1f4kEUwElKMmRS?usp=sharing

The main issue might be in this snippet of the code:

```
for ycell in range(8):
    for xcell in range(13):
        #cells[ycell][xcell] = np.array(vz_new[(y_new == ycell) & (x_new == xcell)],dtype=object)
        cells[ycell][xcell] = vz_new[(y_new == ycell) & (x_new == xcell)]
        #[ i for i in cells[ycell][xcell] if (math.inf not in i) and (math.nan not in i) ]
        
        h3[ycell][xcell] = get_h3(cells[ycell][xcell]) 
        #print(cells[ycell][xcell])
        #print(h3[ycell][xcell])
        
        
        #print('SHAPE IS=', h3[ycell][xcell].shape)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# heatmap
ax=sns.heatmap(h3[ycell][xcell], cmap='RdBu')
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

Not posting full code or error here because too long, so please check google drive link for full code. Thanks for any help! Please ask for clarification if needed.

NOTE: h3 is like a list of lists. looks like the following when printed.
[image]

Comment: you are plotting inside the loops. this will generate a lot of plots nd the plt.show() will halt the execution at each step of the loop. Remove the plots from inside the loops

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, i removed from the loop but same issue..

Comment: ok, what does `get_h3(cells[ycell][xcell])` return? it has to match whatever datatype is in `h3[ycell][xcell]`

Comment: print(type(h3[ycell][xcell])) inside loop gives some values as <class 'int'>  and some are 
<class 'numpy.float64'> and get_h3(cells[ycell][xcell]) match datatype in h3[ycell][xcell]

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki if I replace `ax=sns.heatmap(h3[ycell][xcell], cmap='RdBu')` by `ax=sns.heatmap(h3, cmap='RdBu')`, then gives new error:ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: What is `h3`?  Your code sets elements of it, but doesn't show how it was initialized.  Is a list of lists?  Object dtype array?  For use by `heatmap` it should (judging from the error message) be a 2d numeric dtype array - or a list that can be turned into that.  What does `np.array(h3, dtype=float)` do?

Comment: @hpaulj h3 is a list of lists, I think. when i print h3, it just prints numbers in a long vertical line. When I used `ax=sns.heatmap(np.array(h3, dtype=float))` it gives error  `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (40, 40) + inhomogeneous part.` Also, h3 is initialized as `h3 = [[[] for y_new in range(k)] for x_new in range(k)]`

Comment: What does the `get_h3` produce?  It should be a single number.  I suspect it produces lists or arrays that vary in size.

Comment: @hpaulj i have printed h3 and attached it as an edit on the original post.

Comment: @hpaulj `print('GET_H3=',get_h3(cells[ycell][xcell]))` inside the loop produces single numbers for get_h3

Comment: Pay serious attention to that `h3` display.  Does that look at all like a 2d numpy array (or something that can be turned to one)?

Comment: @hpaulj I had to adjust the h3 dimensions and now it seems to produce a plot..but I will have to check to see if it's producing correct numbers. Basically I had to set both xcell and ycell range to be the same...